# Delay job in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-sqs

I have messages inside amazon SQS. for some of the messages I need to perform a delay of six hours before I can start working on them (the delay is a giving). 
one solution would be to do `Thread.Sleep(6h)`. 
I don't like this solution because I'm afraid something will happen to the thread and I'll lose the data. another solution will be to read the message see if 6 hours have passed, and if not return the message to the queue. again I don't like it because the procedure will happen a lot.
Is there any better solution ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you create individual Multiple Queues and put the queue items separately.

**Example 1:**

You can have 6 queues like Queue0, Queue1, Queue2, Queue3, Queue4, Queue5 and use a hash-function like hash(x) = current-hour % 6 - this function will return values from 0 to 5 and you can put the items in Queue_f(x) and read the queues individually based on current time.

**Example 2:**

If the current time is 01:00 Hours you can create separate queues like Queue0700Hours, if the current time is 02:00 hours you can create a another new queue as Queue0800Hours like wise and go.

This way you are decoupling the need to wait / stop a processing and pick up the producers and consumers independently based on the current timestamp.

Comment: I thought about creating another dedicated queue. I was hoping I could avoid it. Isn't there out of the box solution Amazon provides for delaying a message for several hours?

Comment: The out of the box way would be like adding items to the queue and reading them immediately by another process. Set the queue to have the visibility timeout of 6 hours. This way the queue item is picked as soon as it is pushed and when the item is picked - it is old re appear after 6 hours. To ensure and confidently process the items after 6 hours, you see the retry count to be 1.